# Enable user location picking on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a functionality in Angular app that should enable users to choose where their project is located.
This location data is used across the app.

Is there any way to use Google Maps API so that user can choose where project is located when project is created/modified and later show where that project is located?

If not, are there any libraries that work well with Google Maps where user can input address that could later be added to Google Maps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select a location from the map which can be saved?

Comment: What do you mean by " input address that could later be added to Google Maps"?

Comment: @MuhammadKamran Exactly, user should select a location on a map which could be saved and later project location should be displayed in project details. If that can not work, it would be great if user could type project address inside an input field which will be stored in a variable later injected to Google Maps in order to display location information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete) component to get user location:

And then later on if you want to display the location. You can use the official agm (Angular google maps) module. Which is also a dependency of the above component.

Comment: That looks like just the thing I needed :D I have one more question. Is there any way to make google maps more interactive? I wonder if there is any way to manually move marker inside the google maps for a more precise location pinpoint.

Comment: @Skafec yes you can do that. In the agm module. You have access to the marker. And you can update the marker from your ts and it will update on the map.

Comment: The agm module contains the component which takes marker as an input. Along with other things like polyline etc.
You can read more in their documentation: https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap.

Comment: Just an update, I went with leaflet js library. We were having issues with Google Maps API so we decided to use something else. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Google has some decent [primers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation) to get you started on selecting a geolocation using Google Maps APIs for Javascript.

You might need to implement a combination of:

`Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` & `Geocoder.from(verboseAddress)`

to get the user input either current geolocation or a different POI on Google Maps.

Also see if this earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628568/get-coordinates-of-current-location-in-angular/51629232) helps you.